# why does integral of exponent becomes 1 / something?

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Could anyone explain to me why at step 3, after integration it becomes $1/(a-jw)$?

[image]

Comment: What is an antirderivative of $e^{bt}$ with respect to $t$ and $b$ a constant ?

Comment: Change of variable. $\int e^{at}dt=\int e^{at} \frac 1a adt$. Now choose $z=at$, then $dz=adt$.

Comment: do mathjax not images.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand, I have basic understanding of integration ... after teaching the basics of integration, my lecturer just tossed into our faces Fourier Series and Fourier Transform, could you please explain to me like I am five?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $z=b+ic,b >0$
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-zt} dt=-\left .\frac{e^{-zt}}{z}\right|_{0}^{\infty}=\frac{1}{z}=\frac{1}{b+ic}.$$
As $e^{-zt}$ vanishes at $t=\infty$ if only $\Re(z)=b>0$$

Comment: when you $e^{-zt}$ vanishes at $t = \infty$, do you mean it tends to 0, that's why it vanishes?

Comment: @suinegshtam substitute $t=\infty$, you'll get $e^{-\infty}=0$. So it 'vanishes'

Comment: Yes, "vanishes at $t=\infty$" means the limit is zero as $t \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Integral of exponent does not become 1/something. The basic rule is

$$ \int  e^{ax} dx =  \frac{e^{ax}}{a} +c   ......->1$$

In the integrations you perform above,you integrate, for example, $e^{(a-j\omega)t}$ with respect to $dt$. Put $a-j\omega$ as $a$ above in 1. You just get the coefficient of the variable (wrt which you are performing integration) as the denominator. It happens in logarithmic and trigonometric integrations too. I think learning the basics of integration from any good book will help you.